# Swapping buckets in Couchbase

Tags: database, sdk, couchbase, sql++

Following an [exact question about MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-do-i-swap-tables-in-mysql) tables swap, I like to do the same operation in Couchbase's server buckets.

For example, given buckets of:

`foo` and `foo_new`

I like to swap the names to:

`foo_old` and `foo`

The `MySQL` equivalent command is: `RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_old, foo_new To foo;`

In addition, I like to make this change via Java SDK and not manually.

I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637985/how-to-rename-a-bucket-in-couchbase) that states that it is not possible to change bucket name.

Is it possible in newer version? Till now I was not able to find something that can do it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no N1QL command for renaming buckets. None are planned, either. Since you cannot change the name of a bucket from the UI, it's safe to say there isn't an API for doing this, either.

You would have to use an API command to create a new bucket, a bunch of N1QL commands to create new indexes on the new bucket, and then copy over all the documents from the old bucket to the new, presumably using an INSERT-SELECT.

Unless you are using very small buckets, probably for test purposes, I don't recommend this approach.

Comment: Do you know if it is not support because of certain business logic?

Comment: I don't know why renaming a bucket isn't supported. I think we could support it easily enough, but the need has never been great enough. At some point a big enough customer will ask us for it, and we'll build it.